# How to edit text input fields with Hammer.js Touch Emulator?

Tags: javascript, touch, hammer.js

Using Hammer.js and the Touch Emulator found here:

https://github.com/hammerjs/touchemulator

Cannot seem to click into a text input at all let alone edit it.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out!

When creating the Hammer event add a Tap event to it. In the handler for the tap event focus and click of the target element. This will allow input fields and buttons to be utilized that are wrapped in the Hammer object.

Hammer v2.04

```
var el = document.querySelector("#touchable");
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(el, {});
mc.add(new Hammer.Tap({ }));
mc.on("tap", function (ev) {
       ev.target.focus()//This allows text fields to be focused on
       ev.target.click()//This allows buttons and other objects to be clicked
});
```

This Works best for IOS and Android devices specifically

Comment: are you using the touchemulator?

Comment: Yes, I use TouchEmulator.js as well as hammer.js

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but I have been able to edit inputs by placing this line at the top of the `onMouse` function.

```
if (!ev.shiftKey && ev.target.nodeName === 'INPUT') return;
```

Roughly translated to, no multitouch and you're clicking an input, ok I'll do nothing...